# javascript variable in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, foreach

I try to have a parallax effect for my sections the speed of the parallax are given in the html with data-Lon1 like this

I get back the data-Lon1 and use it in my parallax function for having diferent speed for the sections

```
(function(){

  var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax"),


  window.onscroll = function(){
    [].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function(el,i){
     speed = parseFloat($(el).attr('data-lon1'));
      var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
          elBackgrounPos = "0 " + (windowYOffset * speed) + "px";

      el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;

    });
  };

})();
```

The sections aren't getting the speed value but if I given a speed value by default it works. How could I get each data-Lon1 section value and have three different speed ?

Comment: You forgot the part where you describe a problem and ask a question...

Comment: What random parallax library are you using?

Comment: FYI, `[].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function(el,i){` can be rewritten as  `[].forEach.call(parallax, function(el,i){`. You don't need the `.slice()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *always* going to return the same value:

```
parseFloat($('.parallax').attr('data-lon1'))
```

Because you're selecting *all* matching `.parallax` elements and trying to get *one* value from all of them, which is likely always going to default to the first in the set.

You probably want to get the value for the *specific element* being used in that iteration of the loop:

```
parseFloat($(el).attr('data-lon1'))
```

Comment: @soniamaklouf: Define "doesn't work".  What *does* it do?  How *specifically* does it fail?  When you debug it, where exactly does the problem happen?  Be specific, nobody here can see your screen.

Comment: It gives me ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @soniamaklouf: It would have been giving you *that exact same error* before.  You're trying to use jQuery without loading the jQuery library.